# Access and VBA - default value of field is null?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm making a form with Microsoft Access and I'm trying to make an `AfterUpdate` event procedure for a field. I need to know if the value of that field is the default value (or if it's empy). I read that the default value of a field in VBA is `Null` so I made this:

```
Private Sub EB1_10_Val1_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.EB1_10_Val1.Value = Null Then
        MsgBox "hello"
    End If
End Sub
```

This didn't work so I tried this for when the user updates the value in the field and then erases it (empties the field)

```
Private Sub EB1_10_Val1_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.EB1_10_Val1.Value = Empty Then
        MsgBox "hello"
    End If
End Sub
```

The messages never pop up. On the other hand I tried changing the default value of the field to 0 but Its not working. The 0 doesn't appear in the field as default when in Form View.

Comment: Try checking with `isnull(Me.EB1_10_Val1.Value)` and `isEmpty(Me.EB1_10_Val1.Value)`

Comment: By the way: what kind of field is `Me.EB1_10_Val1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the field is empty with this expression:

```
If IsNull(Me.EB1_10_Val1.Value) Then
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to solution provided by [mielk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3064741/mielk), you can use [Nz](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195223.aspx) or [Iif](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj249300.aspx) function to replace `Null` with default value.

Usage:

```
myVal = Nz(Me.SomTextBox, 0)
```